# How can I overwrite the `->` operator in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

I would like to have R print out the value that is about to be saved as an object any time I use the right-assign operator (`->`).

I tried to do this with:

```
`->` <- compose(`->`, print)
```

but I was met with:

```
Error in list2(...) : object '->' not found
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is that `->` isn't an actual symbol in R. The parser translates that to a `<-` symbol. So `->` is the exact same as `<-`. They can't have different behaviors.

Comment: Interesting. So the parser replaces `a -> b` with `b <- a` before evaluating anything? Sounds like I need to define my own infix operator.